# Issue in using recurrence in SSRS / Dynamic Reports on Sharepoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, recurrence

I am using [Reporting Service with SharePoint List](http://sharepointtaskmaster.blogspot.in/2011/08/make-report-by-reporting-service-with.html)

I am querying a `calendar` list, i have issue fetching recurring items. When i try to use expand recurrence i get the following issue
[image]

The query for recurrence i have is:

```
<RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ListName>SomeList</ListName>
 <Query>
 <Where>
  <DateRangesOverlap>
  <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
  <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
  <FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />
  <Value Type='DateTime'><Today/></Value>
  </DateRangesOverlap>
 </Where>
 </Query>
<QueryOptions>
 <ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>
 <CalendarDate><Today/></CalendarDate>
 <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' />
 </QueryOptions>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
    <FieldRef Name="EndDate" />
    <FieldRef Name="fRecurrence" />
    <FieldRef Name="Hosted_x0020_By" />
    <FieldRef Name="External_x0020_Attendees" />
    <FieldRef Name="Catering_x0020_Requirements" />
    <FieldRef Name="Company" />
    <FieldRef Name="Recurrence_x0020_ID" />
    <FieldRef Name="Room" />
    <FieldRef Name="RecurrenceData" />
  </ViewFields>
</RSSharePointList>
```

is it proper? is there any other way to handle recurrence with Reporting Service? Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formed each XML tag by creating a  new **Parameter** of the type XML.